# How to Render MarkDown inside textarea or inputTextArea using Blazor

Tags: markdown, blazor

How to display markup string inside textarea or inputTextArea in order to use its scroll for larger text

Error message is:Cannot convert markupstring to string

```
@if (HTMLContent != null)
{
    <InputTextArea @bind-Value="@((MarkupString) HTMLContent)">

    </InputTextArea>
    <textarea @bind="@( HTMLContent)">
            @((MarkupString) HTMLContent)
    </textarea>

}

@code {
    [Parameter] public string MarkdownContent { get; set; }
    private string HTMLContent;
    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MarkdownContent))
        {
            HTMLContent = Markdown.ToHtml(MarkdownContent);
        }
        else
        {
            HTMLContent = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i am using MARKDIG Nuget package

Answer (score 1):

I hope, you are already using MarkDig nuget package for this task. Below code will work. Check it here.

**Parent Component**

```html
<Counter MarkdownContent="@parentHtmlContent"></Counter>

@code{
    private string parentHtmlContent = $"<h2><p>Hi, This is Rahul from parent...</p>" +
    $"" +
    $"" +
    $"<p>I am currently working for Blazor projects...</p></h2>";
}
```

**Child Component**

```html
<textarea @bind="@ToHtml"></textarea>

@if (HTMLContent != null)
{
    <textarea @bind="@HTMLContent"></textarea>
}

@code {

    string markString2 = $"<h2><p>Hi, This is Rahul...</p></h2>";

    [Parameter] public string MarkdownContent { get; set; }

    private string HTMLContent;

    public string ToHtml
    {
        get
        {
            return Markdig.Markdown.ToHtml(markString2);
        }
        set
        {
            markString2 = value;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MarkdownContent))
        {
            HTMLContent = Markdig.Markdown.ToHtml(MarkdownContent);
        }
        else
        {
            HTMLContent = null;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Hope, it will help and it is what you want! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the solution from @Rahul but it is a bit overly complicated. I think this blog sums it up well using Markdig: https://jonhilton.net/blazor-markdown-editor/

Steps:

`Install-Package Markdig` in Client project.

Create a new Blazor (Razor) component called `Editor.razor` and add the following values:

```
@page "/markdown"
@inherits MarkdownEditorBase

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <textarea class="form-control" @bind-value="Body" @bind-value:event="oninput"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Body))
        {
            @((MarkupString)Preview)
        }
    </div>
</div>

@code {

}
```

Then add a component base class `Editor.razor.cs` like this:

```
using Markdig;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

public class MarkdownEditorBase : ComponentBase
{
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public string Preview => Markdown.ToHtml(Body);
}
```

Now everything works.

If you would rather have everything in the Blazor component code block that will work fine as well:

```
@page "/markdown"
@using Markdig;

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <textarea class="form-control" @bind-value="Body" @bind-value:event="oninput"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Body))
        {
            @((MarkupString)Preview)
        }
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public string Preview => Markdown.ToHtml(Body);
}
```

Example:

[image]